# How to resolve this grammar ambiguity?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am able to parse the following valid SQL expression:

```
(select 1 limit 1) union all select 1 union all (select 2);
```

However, it seems there is an ambiguity in it, which I've been have a lot of trouble resolving. Here is a working version of the program (I've obviously cut down the statements just to create a minimal producible question) --

```
parser grammar DBParser;
options { tokenVocab = DBLexer;}

root
    : selectStatement SEMI? EOF
    ;

selectStatement
     : (selectStatementWithParens|selectClause|setOperation)
     limitClause?
     ;

selectClause
    : SELECT NUMBER
    ;

limitClause
    : LIMIT NUMBER
    ;
 
selectStatementWithParens
    : OPEN_PAREN selectStatement CLOSE_PAREN
    ;

setOperation:
    (selectClause | selectStatementWithParens)
    (setOperand (selectClause | selectStatementWithParens))*
    ;

setOperand
    : UNION ALL?
    ;
```

```
lexer grammar DBLexer;
options { caseInsensitive=true; }
SELECT              :           'SELECT';                   // SELECT *...
LIMIT               :           'LIMIT';                    // ORDER BY x LIMIT 20
ALL                 :           'ALL';                      // SELECT ALL vs. SELECT DISTINCT; WHERE ALL (...); UNION ALL...
UNION               :           'UNION';                    // Set operation

SEMI                :           ';';                        // Statement terminator
OPEN_PAREN          :           '(';                        // Function calls, object declarations
CLOSE_PAREN         :           ')';

NUMBER
     : [0-9]+
    ;

WHITESPACE
    : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
    ;
```

Where is the ambiguity coming from, and what could be a possible way to solve this?

---

**Update**: I'm not sure if this is the solution, but it seems the following helped eliminate that ambiguity:

```
 selectStatement:
     withClause?
     (selectStatementWithParens|selectClause)
     (setOperand (selectClause|selectStatementWithParens))*
     orderClause?
     (limitClause offsetClause?)?
     ;
```

In other words -- making it such that the `setOperand` doesn't re-start with the `select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `setOpertaion` rule can match single `selectClause` or `selectStatementWithParens` (because you use the `*` cardinality for the second half of the rule, so 0 instances of the second half still matches the rule).  This means that a `selectClause` can match the `selectClause` rule in `selectStatement`, or it could be used to construct a `setOperation` (which is the other alternative in your ambiguity).

If you change `setOperation` to use `+` cardinality for the second half of the rule, you resolve the ambiguity.

```
setOperation
    : (selectClause | selectStatementWithParens)
      (setOperand (selectClause | selectStatementWithParens))+
    ;
```

This also seems logical, that you'd only want to consider something a `setOperation` if there's a `setOperand` involved.

That explains and corrects the ambiguity, but still leaves you with a "max k" of 7.

Comment: thanks for this! I get the "max k" down to 1 when I use the approach I mentioned in he update, basically so that the setOperation starts on the operand instead of re-starting on the select.

Comment: I suspect that is going to give you an "awkward" parse tree to work with.  The first part of you "actual" set operation will be on a completely different node of the parse tree.  Be careful that your grammar results in a useful parse tree rather than is just capable of consuming your input.

Comment: oh that's pretty interesting, I hadn't thought of that before...taking that advice then I'll also rewrite the grammar around the JOIN, which handled things in a similar case. Is there any downside though of having the K at 7?

Comment: I believe that's a measure of just how many tokens the parser may have to evaluate before it can decide which parser rule to match.  As such, it can have performance implications.  As with most things, you probably want to work on getting the right results and then look into performance.  I haven't dived deeply enough into what you have to determine why there's so much look ahead.

Comment: does that look like an OK parse tree to work with? https://gyazo.com/73968b39412ff64398b2f4be006670e1